# How to render image in Matlab off screen?

Tags: matlab, graphics

I have a set of planar convex polygons in 3D that I can render in Matlab using `patch`. As part of my code though, I need to efficiently render the patches to the image plane of a virtual camera in the 3D environment.

The algorithm I'm basing my code used OpenGL raytracing to render the image, but I don't know how I could do this in or from Matlab.

How can I do this rendering quickly from within a matlab script?

Comment: have you considered using `figure` with no visibility? than capturing the figure using `getframe`?

Comment: Yes, but AFAIK I don't have sufficient control over the camera position, parameters, and perspective to accurately reproduce and render the scene.

Comment: Have you looked at [`axes` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html)? There are quite a few Camera properties, and also 'Projection' property. There are quite a few controls over [`lighting`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lighting.html) and [`light`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/light.html). I think these links are a good starting point.